# JPA: Mapping a list of enums to an entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have two tables

employee:

```
id | ...
```

employee_statusgroup:

```
employee_id | statusgroup
```

and want to get all the statusgroups (its an enum) of an employee in the employee entity.

I tried this

```
@ElementCollection(targetClass = StatusGroup::class)
@Enumerated(STRING)
@CollectionTable(name = "employee_statusgroup")
@Column(name = "statusgroup")
var statusGroups: MutableList<StatusGroup> = mutableListOf(),
```

but when I try to save an employee with updated statusgroups, I get this exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement [ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "employee_statusgroup_pk"
```

What do I do wrong? Thanks in advance.